# cannot find error in my notes.js for notepad application

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am following a tutorial on `node.js` and I am creating a notepad in pure node. I have three files: `app.js` , `notes.js` and my `notes-data.json` file. I am getting an error in my `notes.js` and it's giving me a hard time. The error that I am getting is `TypeError: notes.push is not a function`. I will post the code down below.

`app.js code:`

```
console.log("Starting app.js");

const _ = require('lodash');
const yargs = require('yargs');

// fetching fs module and storing in variable fs
const fs = require('fs');



// parses the same argv array that node does 
const argv  = yargs.argv;
// we are requiring the the notes.js file
const notes = require('./notes.js');

//console.log(process.argv);

//console.log("Process", process.argv);
console.log("Yargs" , argv);

var command = argv._[0];
console.log("Command: " , command);

if(command === "add"){
//console.log("Adding new note");
notes.addNote(argv.title , argv.body);
}
else if(command === "list")
{
console.log("listing all notes");
notes.getAll();
} 
else if (command === "read")
{
console.log("now reading notes");
notes.getNote(argv.title);
}
else if(command === "remove")
{
console.log("Now removing notes");
notes.removeNotes(argv.title , argv.body);
}
else
{
console.log("command not recognized");
}
```

`notes.js code`

```
console.log("starting notes.js");

const fs = require('fs');


var fetchNotes = () => {
    try{
    // this part will allow us to keep adding notes without
    // removing whats already there
   return fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');
   notes = JSON.parse(notesString);

    }catch(e){
        return [];

    }
};

var saveNotes = (notes) => {
fs.writeFileSync('notes-data.json' , JSON.stringify(notes));

 };

var addNote = (title ,body) => {
// empty array
var notes = fetchNotes();
// represents a new note
var note = {
    title,
    body
};

// filtering for duplicate notes
var duplicateNote = notes.filter((note) => {
    return note.title === title;
});


if(duplicateNote.length === 0){
// pushing the new note to the notes
notes.push(note);
saveNotes(notes);
}
};




var getAll = () => {
console.log("Getting all Notes");
console.log('Listing Notes', process.argv[2]);
};

var getNote = (title) => {
console.log("Reading " , title)
 };

var removeNotes = (title) => {
console.log("Now removing " , title);
};


module.exports = {
// this is ES6 syntax
addNote,
getAll,
getNote, 
removeNotes
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `fetchNotes` function both `return`s something and also sets the global `notes`. If `notes` doesn't exist, then, you return an array... and do nothing with it. Set `notes = []` or return and set the variable outside of that function.

Here's an example of setting notes inside the function

```
notes = undefined;
function fetchNotes = () => {
  <...>
  notes = <result of readFileSync>
}

fetchNotes();
// notes is now the result
```

Here's the other

```
notes = undefined;
function fetchNotes = () => {
  <...>
  return <result of readFileSync>
}

notes = fetchNotes();
// notes is now the result
```

Note that the main difference is that I have to assign the *result of the function* in the second example, whereas in the first I'm just setting a *global variable*.

In my experience, the second example is the preferable way of doing this, as it avoids global variables (which are *usually* bad). However, for a small program like this, the first way may make more sense.

Hope this helps!

Comment: having it return an empty array or setting notes = [] is the same thing isn't it?

Comment: @jsilva I edited my response with some examples. Let me know if that makes sense :)

Comment: I was able to find the error in the code. Thanks for providing examples since they also cleared it up.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the source of the error inside of your `addNote` named method, where you call `notes.push(note)`. That particular error in conjunction with how you've used it seems to point to the `notes` variable containing data that does not support the `push` method.

This is probably happening because inside of `addNote`, you declare the `notes` variable as the returned data from the `fetchNotes` method. Inside of `fetchNotes`, you return the result of an `fs.readFileSync` call, which according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options), returns a string or buffer.

I don't believe either of those data types in JavaScript support the `push` method.

As someone else has mentioned, you should define `notes` as an array, which will definitely support `push`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are returning from the function `fetchNotes` before assigning `notes`.

`return fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');
 notes = JSON.parse(notesString);`

Answer (score -1):

Likely: `fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json', 'utf8');`